# pass two variables with ajax after push to array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make this code to work but it look I'm doing something wrong when passing the two variables with ajax, please help, here is the code, basically is a drag and drop code to move items between boxes and organize inside each box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Example 1.3: Sortable and connectable lists with visual helper
    $('#sortable-div .sortable-list').sortable({
      connectWith: '#sortable-div .sortable-list',
      placeholder: 'placeholder',
      delay: 150,
      stop: function() {
        var selectedData = new Array();
        $('.sortable-list>li').each(function() {
          selectedData.push([$(this).attr("id"), $(this).attr("pagenum")])

        });
        updateOrder(selectedData);
      }

    });
  });

  function updateOrder(data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajaxPro.php",
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        position: data,
        page: data
      },
      success: function() {
        /* alert('your change successfully saved');*/
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Provide a more detailed explanation of what isn't working properly. Also why do you send same array for both `position` and `page`?

Comment: position and page are the same thing? data is an array so in your php page how do you receive the data? Have you got some errors?

Comment: have you tried to `JSON.stringify` your data? then `json_decode` on php.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using this way:

```
$('.spremiUredivanje').click(function(){

    ai = document.getElementById('ai_mjerila_edit').value;
    broj_mjerila = document.getElementById('broj_mjerila_edit').value;
    adresa = document.getElementById('adresa_edit').value;
    stanje = document.getElementById('stanje_edit').value;
    $( "#datum_edit" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" ); 
    datum =  document.getElementById('datum_edit').value;
    operater = document.getElementById('operater_edit').value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            post1: broj_mjerila, post2: adresa, post3:stanje, post4: datum, post5: operater, post6:ai
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loaderEdit').show();
        },
```

So your php file should look like this:

```
$broj_mjerila = $_POST['post1'];
$adresa = $_POST['post2'];
$stanje = $_POST['post3'];
$datum = $_POST['post4'];
$operater = $_POST['post5'];
$ai = $_POST['post6'];
```

To control your response use `success` inside ajax call:

```
success: function(response) {
            if(response == 1) {
                //alert("success!");
                $('#editUspjesan').show();
                $('#loaderEdit').hide();...
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to a different question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your requirement clear. Are you trying to get page number and id in 2 separate array?

```
// If page no and id need to be in separate array
var position = [], pages = [];
$('.sortable-list>li').each(function() {
     position.push($(this).attr("id"));
     pages.push($(this).attr("pagenum"));
});
updateOrder(position, pages);

function updateOrder(position, page) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajaxPro.php",
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        position: position,
        page: page
      },
      success: function() {
        /* alert('your change successfully saved');*/
      }
    })
  }


// If page no and id can be combined use objects
var selectedData = [];
$('.sortable-list>li').each(function() {
    selectedData.push({id: $(this).attr("id"), page: $(this).attr("pagenum")})
});
function updateOrder(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxPro.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
        position: data
    },
    success: function() {
        /* alert('your change successfully saved');*/
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Example 1.3: Sortable and connectable lists with visual helper
$('#sortable-div .sortable-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '#sortable-div .sortable-list',
  placeholder: 'placeholder',
  delay: 150,
  stop: function() {
    var selectedData = new Array();
    $('.sortable-list>li').each(function() {
      selectedData.push([$(this).attr("id"), $(this).attr("pagenum")])

    });
    updateOrder(selectedData);
  }

});
});

function updateOrder(data) {
$.ajax({
  url: "ajaxPro.php",
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    position: data.id,
    page: data.pagenum
  },
dataType:'json',
  success: function() {
    /* alert('your change successfully saved');*/
  }
})
}
</script>
```

Let's try this one